# How to have USB act as a programmable power source?

Tags: usb, wire, usb-device, wire-terminals

I am interested in making a USB device that on 1 end, is a male usb that plugs into a PC like windows. On the other end is something that has a positive and negative terminal (or wire end). I want to then connect it to a 3v DC motor. You can see here

https://youtu.be/3Tn-ehctodE?t=247

To power the motor, I just need to connect a wire from it's positive terminal to a positive terminal from a power source and its negative terminal to a negative terminal from a power source.

So I want the USB cable to be the powersource when connected to the pc. Then at the same time, I want to be able to write code in some language that can turn on and off the power.

Lastly, I would like to be able to connect multiple motors to it, but I think I can achieve that with a breadboard as a middle man.

Does anyone know how I would go about this, or if there is some device already out there that can do this?

Thanks

EDIT: I am not sure, but it might be this

https://www.ekmmetering.com/collections/meter-reading-solutions/products/ekm-blink-rs-485-to-usb-converter?gclid=CjwKCAjw8uLcBRACEiwAaL6MSTkiYhQrK4YfZQ1_qsO7BwgWwkmavCLVi6LeLylQ7n0VyvijeHdLoBoCGKgQAvD_BwE

Comment: Questions asking for a complete solution ("How do I go about ...") or for a product recommendation are closed here. Having said that,  I think you should look into USB-friendly microcontrollers (like Arduino) rather than trying to manipulate the USB power lines via software. Also, if your motors draw any substantial current (more than 150mA or so) you will quickly discover that powering motors from USB requires careful design (soft-start or similar) otherwise you get problems with stall currents.

Answer (score 1):

USB port from the PC can only supply a limited amount of current, typically 500mA is the max. You are not going to drive very many motors with that.  Even 1 could  be too much.  You can power an Arduino from the PC, have it control motor drivers (could be as simple as a transistor), with the motors powered from something else, like a couple of C cells or D cells if you want a 3V source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arduino (mini, uno or pro) to run the 5V DC motor by coding. Arduino code is very handy and simple. Go through the link given below
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/control-a-motor-with-an-arduino/

Comment: Answers that are just a link to another site do not have lasting value. The question is really asking about about using a USB cable to power motors, and you didn't address that at all.